# How to measure speed of php scripts independantly of eachother? Various Methods?

Tags: php, time, performance, delay

On my website various php codes run from various programmers from whom I have bought project scripts. Some use a session ( session start etc...)
Some use external include php files and do their math within there and return or echo some things. Some run only when asked to, like the search script.

`Is there an easy way for me to monitor, temporary, all the various scripts's their delays in millisecond sothat I can see whats going on below the water?`

I have seen once a programmer making something and below the page there were these long listst of sentences and various ms numbers etc.

**Q1. Is there a default php function for this?** How do I call/toggle this?
**Q2. What are the various methods** with which such calculations are made?
**Q3. How reliable are they?** are those milliseconds theory or actual real world result?

Thanks for your insight!
Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No defualt method i can thnik of. But its easy.At the start of your script simply place this:

```
$s = microtime(true);
```

and at the end

```
$e = microtime(true);
echo  round($e - $s, 2) . " Sec";
```

Normally you would leave the second parameter of round() as it is, but if you find that your script reports the time as ’0 Sec’ increase the number until you get an answer.[check this for more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Comment: Freaking awesome simple! Thank you very much ayush +1, I get now one single numer, when i put the start at the top and end at the very bottom I get 0,02  Now, how can i put multiple echoes along the way so it gives me a journey log along the way with added delays or, better yet, independantly time values for every piece?

Comment: Thanks I overlooked the hyperlink! Great Think this will do fine for my usage for now...

Comment: just use microtime() anywhere in your script and then round() the difference from $s.use larger values instead of 2 FOR HIGHER precision.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running an Apache webserver, then you should have the [apache benchmarking tool](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) that can give some very accurate information about script timings, even simulating numbers of concurrent users.

From a web browser, the Firebug extension of Firefox can also be useful as a tool for seeing how long your own requests take.

Neither of these methods is purely a timer for the PHP code though

Comment: Thanks Mark, have no acces to that im afraid but your tip for highest accuracy is +1

Answer (score 1):

The easiest/fastest way is to install a debugging extension that supports profiling, like [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/). You can then run a profiling tool (e.g.: [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)) to profile your scripts, graph the results, and figure out what uses the most memory, execution time, etc.

It also provides various other functionalities like stack tracing, etc.

Comment: Reminds me of SpaceMonger which creates a graphical representation of harddisc usage. Can this be implemented on shared hosting? looks very complex to install, if allowed at all on shared hosting? +1

Comment: It depends on your hosting provider. Some may allow you to load the extension/recompile, some may have it loaded already. In most cases, unfortunately, it isn't the case. All I know is that Dreamhost may allow you to. Other than that, I can't tell.